# Multi-threading in SBCL via Slime creates threads that do not return or close

Tags: multithreading, common-lisp, sbcl, slime

I am trying to use the common lisp machine learning library [clml](https://github.com/mmaul/clml) with:

- Ubuntu 14.04 LT
- Emacs 24
- SLIME 2.10.1
- SBCL 1.2.3

When I run the following example using SBCL started in the terminal everything works, four threads are created, return the result and close. When I run the same code from within SLIME the following works just fine:

```
(setf *read-default-float-format* 'double-float)
(ql:quickload :clml)
(in-package :clml.decision-tree.random-forest)

(defparameter *bc-train*)
(setf *bc-train* (read-data-from-file (clml.utility.data:fetch "https://mmaul.github.io/clml.data/sample/bc.train.csv")
                                  :type :csv
                                  :csv-type-spec
                                  (append (loop for i below 9 collect 'double-float) '(string))))
```

When I attempt to train the random forest with `make-regression-forest`:

```
 (defparameter *regression-forest*)
 (setf *regression-forest* (make-regression-forest *bc-train* "Cell.size"))
```

The following happens:

- the slime repl is still responsive
- four threads are created, they do not use any CPU time, and do not return or exit.
- the inferior-lisp buffer shows the following fatal error for each of the threads:

  lbd> fatal error encounter in SBCL pid #### (tid ##########):
  GC invariant lost, file "thread.c", line 910

`make-regression-forest` uses the clml [futures](https://github.com/mmaul/clml/tree/master/addons/future) package which is reportedly similar to eager-future.

I would like to use SLIME to experiment with this package and would be happy to try to use a different multi-threading approach if needed.

Many thanks,

Comment: you may want to see if that is a reproducible bug and report that on the SBCL mailing list.

Comment: Okay thanks will do, I may try the slime mailing list as well since this works when SBCL is started from the command prompt.